# Put files in windows CE .NET Emulator, directory not found in emulator

Tags: c#, exception, windows-mobile

I needed to test a mobile application that runs on Windows CE .NET Emulator. I'm using Microsoft Visual C# .NET 2003. When I run the application, on some point this message appears

Error Message:

An unheadled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The application has a set path and file to search in order to run. It seems that the emulator is trying to access the directory and the files inside the directory however it can't find it in the emulator.

How can I transfer my files that it needs to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the files to your solution, mark them as "content" and set them to Copy Always.

Comment: How do I copy my folders, it only copies the files. I need the whole folder for my program to work.

Comment: Add the entire folder to the app and mark all files as appropriate.  The otehr option is to share a folder in the Emulator's config and get them from the PC that way.